# What is wrong in the below gradle task?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, devops

I just started learning gradle. Tried to create a simple task as shown below:

```
["ab","cd","ef"].each { flavor ->
task hi {
    doLast {
        "println ${flavor}"
    }
}
}
```

while excuting above task ,getting error: Cannot add task 'hi' as a task with that name already exists.

Can someone  please  tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: You're trying to declare task "hi" 3 times - once for every element in the list. You probably want to declare tasks with different names. E.g. `task("hi-${flavor}") { doLast { ... } }`

Comment: The `each` statement is a loop, so the task gets created on every iteration. Put the loop inside the `doLast` to solve this.